# Differentiate the following function $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, derived-functors

$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$, find $f'(x)$.

I know I have to use the quotient rule but, but I got confused by the square root?

Comment: Do you mean $$y=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$$?

Comment: would it be the same saying (1-x)^1/2 / (1+x)^1/2

Comment: square root of the whole thing, the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use the power and the chain rule:
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{-1/2}\left(\frac{-1(1+x)-(1-x)}{(1+x)^2}\right)$$

Comment: guys a bit confused, that first part Dr.Sonnhard makes perfect sense, but what do i use the chain rule for? do i use chain rule then quotient rule or chain rule product rule and quotient rule? whats what?

Comment: Dear Nadia, for $$\frac{1-x}{1+x}$$ you must use the Quotient rule

Comment: $$\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$$

Comment: for what do i use the chain rule?

Comment: it looks like 1/2 (1-x / 1+x ) should be solved by the product rule, but then there is also a power of -1/2 which i dont know what to do with

Comment: The chain rule for the first part:$$\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$$

Comment: It is the formula $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$

Comment: ok so if i use chain rule for that y= sqrt of 'u' and 'u' = (1-x) / (1+x) ?

Comment: no you must use the chain rule for $$\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: ok so then i make 1/2 = u and y= (1-x) / (1+x) ^u ?

Comment: No, it is $$(1-x)^{1/2}/(1+x)^{1/2}$$

Comment: ok then i will come to Ireland

Comment: i understand where to use the quotient rule, but could you tell me what my 'u' and 'y' are for the chain rule?

Comment: You need to look up the chain rule. How would you differentiate $y = t^{\frac{1}{2}}$? You need to do the same thing here, except now $t = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$. And now you just need to use $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \times \frac{dt}{dx}$...

Comment: If this was a home work then write the solution into your notebook

Comment: for example if i have a function e^xsin(x) my u= xsin(x) and Y= e^u And du/dx i get by applying the product rule and dy/du = e^u

Comment: I have an exam tomorrow

Comment: Oh i wish you all the best for tomorrow!

Comment: I've given you a pretty clear solution about applying the chain rule above... But by your method, here $y = u^{\frac{1}{2}}$, where $u = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$

Comment: perfect thats all i was looking for :) give me a minute i will try to calculate

Comment: ok so now I got the equation you gave me initially, but I dont know how to simplify it

Comment: I would write $$y'=-\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

A couple of ways...

**1) Square both sides and implicit differentiation:**

Let $y = \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$, then $y^2 = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$.

Hence $$2y \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(1+x)(-1) - (1-x)(1)}{(1+x)^2}$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2y} \times \frac{-2}{(1+x)^2} = -\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} $$

Haven't spelt the last step out explicitly, but work through it and replace $y$ and you'll get to the result...

**2) Chain rule:**

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \times \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)$$ $$\Rightarrow\frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \times \frac{(1+x)(-1)-(1-x)(1)}{(1+x)^2}$$ and this simplifies to the exact same result, which was $$\frac{dy}{dx}= -\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} $$

Comment: the result should be -1 / sqrt of (1-x)(1+x^3)

Comment: I presume you've made a typo and mean $(1+x)^3$ at the bottom, in which case they are clearly the same: you just need to think a bit... 

$$-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} = -\sqrt{\frac{(1+x)}{(1+x)^4(1-x)}} = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{(1+x)^3(1-x)}} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x)^3(1-x)}} $$

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to apply the rule for composition: $(g(h(x)))'=g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x)$. 
You obtain $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}}\cdot (\frac{1-x}{1+x})'$. 
Try to finish from here.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left( \sqrt{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} \right)= \frac{\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right)}{2\sqrt{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}}= \frac{\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)} }{2\sqrt{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}}= \frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{2g^2(x)\sqrt{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} } $$ 
I hope that this can help

Comment: could you put it in simple terms it looks very confusing

Comment: you can just replace $1-x$ instead of $f(x)$ and $1+x$ instead of $g(x)$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use logarithmic differentiation
$$f=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\implies \log(f)=\frac 12 \log(1-x)-\frac 12 \log(1+x)$$

$$\frac{f'}f=-\frac 12 \frac 1 {1-x}-\frac 12 \frac 1 {1+x}=-\frac 1{(1+x)(1-x)}$$ Now $$f'=f \times \frac{f'}f$$ and simplify.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to differentiate $f(x)= \left(\frac{1- x}{1+ x}\right)^{1/2}$?  Your title implies that you want to differentiate some other function with respect to f!

Using the "chain rule" the derivative is $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1- x}{1+ x}\right)^{-1/2}$ times the derivative of $\frac{1- x}{1+ x}$.  Using the "quotient rule", $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'= \frac{f'g- fg'}{g^2}$, the derivative of the fraction is $\frac{-1(1+ x)- 1(1- x)}{(1+ x)^2}= \frac{-2}{(1+ x)^2}$.

So $f'= \frac{-2}{(1+ x)^2}\left(\frac{1- x}{1+ x}\right)^{-1/2}$.